# How to lauch Windows 8 Apps with no UAC while being "Super-Admin"?

Tags: windows-8, administrator, uac, modern-ui

Under Windows 8; if you activate the default *"Built-in Administrator"* account, you can't launch Windows 8 Metro Interface Apps anymore.

Windows says : *"This application cannot be activated by the built-in administrator account"*.

However, when, on this built-in administrator account, we activate the so-called "UAC", then, it becomes possible to use the Metro applications.

When we use a standard Administrator account with no UAC, copying or editing a file in the *"C:\"* partition pops a message saying *"You must be Administrator to do this"*.

This we can passed by clicking *"Ok"*. However, the message still pops for every modification we do in that partition.

My question is : ***With no UAC and the built-in administrator account, is there a way to use the Metro applications ?***

In short : ***How can I have the full rights to use my Personnal Computer like I wish to ?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no way** to run Windows Store Apps while having full admin permissions. You must activate UAC. The complete sandbox in which store apps run depend on the UAC.

Answer (score 0):

1.Run **Regedit**.

2.goto: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\`

3.Find **DWORD** named **EnableLUA**.

4.Change value from 0 to 1

Source: http://teamwindows8.com/2013/04/how-to-run-metro-apps-in-windows-8-with-uac-turned-off/

Comment: This activates UAC again and is the default behavior. But he wants to disable UAC and run apps.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem: can't run apps with built-in administrator account.

Different solution without disabling UAC:

The Group Policy Editor is not available for Windows 8.1 (not Pro). I did find one, but it doesn't cover all the settings.

Instead I used registry hacks:

1. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
   FilterAdministratorToken 0 Default 1 enabled   Change to 1
2. Use [this](http://www.askvg.com/tip-disable-microsoft-account-sign-in-requirement-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/) method if you're not running Windows 8.1 Pro.
3. Restart your computer.

Sports/Weather is now running, but I haven't tried other apps yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar UAC related threads such as this one from 6 years ago: [How to run UWP Apps with UAC turned off?](https://superuser.com/questions/986957/how-to-run-uwp-apps-with-uac-turned-off/1663432#1663432)

Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 10 until version 1607 doesn't support Metro/UWP apps with the EnableLUA registry being turned off and it will not allow it to run with the exception of Settings only Windows 10 1703 and higher. So the issue is related to version of Windows your running.