# How to run UWP Apps with UAC turned off?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I have turned UAC off for some reasons on Windows 10 using this registry method:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/currentversion/policies/system

EnableLUA ==> 0
```

Which is what I want. Because the programs I often use need administrator access.

But when I open UWP apps like Edge, Store, Weather, They tell me they can't run and you have to enable UAC again (which I don't want to).

Is there anyway to use these apps again without turning UAC on?

Comment: Is this for a regular user account or administrator?

Comment: administrator account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 10 versions until 1607 have sandbox that doesn't allow Metro apps to run without UAC except for Settings. Windows 10 version 1703 and later  have fixed Windows Store UWP apps that allows it to run without UAC.

The proof of Windows 10 1703 and later stating that running UWP apps while disabled UAC are seen in this Winaero link:

https://winaero.com/run-apps-uac-disabled-windows-10/

However if your in Windows 10 right now, you can have the free upgrade to newer versions.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this 6 year old question to get a new answer! Anyways I just gave up and enabled UAC again (I'm on 21H1 now)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run any apps that are now known as universal apps with UAC turned off.

Universal apps run in sandbox environment now which is fully UAC reliant. Even Windows calculator runs this way so with UAC off you cannot run these apps no way around it.

This has been the case since Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, I've had these problem since Windows 8, but it wasn't a problem since I were able to use Windows photo viewer, the Calculator from Win 7, ...

Comment: Isn't there a way?

Comment: @iFarbod - No;  **There is absolutely no way to do what you want.**  The photo viewer and calculator on Windows 8 were not Windows Store Applications.